# SQL Server 2005 error while starting service

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am getting error while starting the service & errorlog is:

```
2013-04-04 14:50:49.14 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.1399.06 (Intel X86) 
    Oct 14 2005 00:33:37 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition on Windows NT 5.1 (Build 2600: Service Pack 2)

2013-04-04 14:50:49.14 Server      (c) 2005 Microsoft Corporation.
2013-04-04 14:50:49.14 Server      All rights reserved.
2013-04-04 14:50:49.14 Server      Server process ID is 312.
2013-04-04 14:50:49.14 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG'.
2013-04-04 14:50:49.14 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 3072 at 4/4/2013 2:32:28 PM (local) 4/4/2013 9:02:28 AM (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2013-04-04 14:50:49.14 Server      Registry startup parameters:
2013-04-04 14:50:49.14 Server        -d C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
2013-04-04 14:50:49.14 Server        -e C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG
2013-04-04 14:50:49.14 Server        -l C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2013-04-04 14:50:49.18 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-04-04 14:50:49.18 Server      Detected 2 CPUs. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2013-04-04 14:50:49.84 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2013-04-04 14:50:49.85 Server      Database Mirroring Transport is disabled in the endpoint configuration.
2013-04-04 14:50:49.90 spid3s      Starting up database 'master'.
2013-04-04 14:50:50.60 spid3s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2013-04-04 14:50:50.64 spid3s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2013-04-04 14:50:50.82 spid8s      Starting up database 'model'.
2013-04-04 14:50:50.82 spid3s      Server name is 'COMPAQ-FB238749\SQLEXPRESS'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-04-04 14:50:50.82 spid3s      Starting up database 'msdb'.
2013-04-04 14:50:50.90 Server      Error: 17190, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2013-04-04 14:50:50.90 Server      FallBack certificate initialization failed with error code: 1.
2013-04-04 14:50:50.90 Server      Warning:Encryption is not available, could not find a valid certificate to load.
2013-04-04 14:50:50.93 Server      Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\SQLLocal\SQLEXPRESS ].
2013-04-04 14:50:50.93 Server      Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\sql\query ].
2013-04-04 14:50:50.98 Server      Dedicated administrator connection support was not started because it is not available on this edition of SQL Server. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-04-04 14:50:51.00 Server      SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2013-04-04 14:50:51.03 spid8s      Error: 9003, Severity: 20, State: 1.
2013-04-04 14:50:51.03 spid8s      The log scan number (100:384:1) passed to log scan in database 'model' is not valid. This error may indicate data corruption or that the log file (.ldf) does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error occurred during replication, re-create the publication. Otherwise, restore from backup if the problem results in a failure during startup. 
2013-04-04 14:50:51.03 spid8s      SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
```

Comment: Are you checking back to confirm the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `[model]` database has become corrupted in some or another way, in particular, SQL is reporting that the log scan failed.

If you had a customised model database, you should probably have a backup of it too.

You would need your installation media to recreate the system databases, and thereafter (if you have one) restore the latest backup of your `[model]` database.

You can achieve this by running the following command line :

`start /wait <CD or DVD Drive>\setup.exe /qn INSTANCENAME=<Instance> REINSTALL=SQL_Engine REBUILDDATABASE=1 SAPWD=<NewStrongPassword>`

This will set you up with an instance without your user databases and all default settings.  You can then proceed with the restore of your `[master]`, `[msdb]`, and `[model]`, and also the rest of your databases.